# How to open netbeans project from other partitions

Tags: filesystem, partitioning, netbeans

I just switch to ubuntu.

After setting up netbeans, I tried to open a netbeans' project from another partition (not partition that setup ubuntu).

Is this possible?

What can I do to access my project?

Comment: Please run these commands from a terminal: `ls /opt | grep netbeans` and `ls -al /home/$USER | grep "*netbeans*"` and post into you question. It appears you don't understand how Linux file system is setup

Answer (score 0):

You need to first mount that partition on some point mount point (a directory if you want) on your computer.

For example, let's say you have a `~/windows_partition` folder, you could :

- identify the name of the other partition on which your NetBeans project isvwith the output of `sudo fdisk -l`. e.g. `/dev/sda3` or using `gparted`
- use `sudo mount /dev/sda3 ~/windows_partition` to mount the partition on the folder.
- you can now access the folder on which your NetBeans project is from the folder on which you mounted the partition